# ruby uniq with replacement

Tags: ruby, uniq

Normal `uniq`:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4].uniq => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I want to replace the duplicate with a replacement at where it was.

Is there a method or way to achieve something like this?

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4].uniq_with_replacement(-1) => [1, 2, 3, -1, -1, 4]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a one-liner:

`a.fill{ |i| a.index(a[i]) == i ? a[i] : -1 }`

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?:

```
class Array
  def uniq_with_replacement(v)
    map.with_object([]){|value, obj| obj << (obj.include?(value) ? v : value) }
  end
end
```

Now:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4].uniq_with_replacement(-1)
# => [1, 2, 3, -1, -1, 4]

[1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4].uniq_with_replacement(-1)
# => [1, 2, 3, -1, -1, -1, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

1 more:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4]
value = -1

a = arr.each_with_index.to_a
  #=> [[1, 0], [2, 1], [3, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [4, 5]]

b = (a - a.uniq(&:first)).map(&:last)
  #=> [3, 4]

arr.map.with_index { |e,i| b.include?(i) ? value : e }
  #=> [1, 2, 3, -1, -1, 4]
```

Comment: Reading code written by people with science or university studies background is always a pleasure. Very good idea!